# How can I force nginx site hosted on Synology NAS to update cache?

Tags: nginx, caching, synology

Good day all!

A few years ago I built an website on my Synology NAS for internal use at my business.
It is hosted using Nginx via the Synology "Web Station" app.

Often, when I make changes to the web site the changes will not reflect on employees browsers unless the cache is cleared.

I am aware that normally i would make changes to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/SITE_IN_QUESTION.

However, this file is overwritten every time the NAS reboots. Presumable with the settings from the web-station app. I don't see any cache settings in the app.

I guess I can make a script that runs at boot to update the file, but It seems like there should be a better way.

I am in no way an expert or even a novice at this kind of stuff,
So any suggestion would be great!

-Thanks!